# Easiest method to configure clang++ to use g++/gcc STL headers in Cygwin?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, g++, clang

I'm running the most up to date versions of clang++ (v3.1) and g++/gcc (v4.7.3) in Cygwin (32-bit).  Everything is using the installed default configuration.  This is a fresh install of Cygwin in Windows 8.

My issue is that clang++ cannot find the installed g++ STL headers to compile my project.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <thread>

    int main() {
        std::mutex myMutext;
        return 0;
    }
```

This sample code results in this error when compiled. Notice the libc stdlib.h header compiles without error.  It's that  isn't found. I've tried other STL headers as a test, same error.

clang++ -c -o test.o test.cpp

```
    test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'mutex' file not found
    #include <mutex>
              ^
    1 error generated.
```

After some searching it seems the suggested options are recompiling the entire clang project and adding the header paths to its source **or** manually adding *all* the g++ STL header paths to my makefile both of which seem kind of hacky.

There has to be an easier option, right?

Comment: The STL headers are not part of g++, which is just the compiler, not the runtime library. Looking at `/usr/include/c++/4.7/mutex` on my Ubuntu system, the header comments say "This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clang++` will be *build* (compile-time) against specific versions of `libstdc++` by default (IIRC). It will not check the system for newer versions at runtime.

The `libstdc++` the `clang-3.1` package of cygwin seems to use is `gcc-4.5.3`, as indicated by the output of `clang++ -v test.cc`. `gcc-4.5.3` is not installed in your enviroment, however.

Your options, none of which are great:

- Downgrade `gcc` to 4.5.3 via the setup. However your C++11 code will still not compile, due to lack of support in the `libstc++` that comes with `gcc-4.5.3`.
- Build `clang` yourself, against the newer `gcc`.
- Build `clang` yourself, with [`libc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/). However, it is highly unlikely Windows is (fully) supported by it.
- Use `gcc-4.7` instead. The Windows support is far more mature in `gcc` right now anyway (and don't get me started about cross-compilers).

(Aside: you'll need `-std=c++11` to compile your code)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have solve it, but I have a simpler solution: just make s symlink of 4.7.3 to 4.5.3 and compile your code with -lstdc++ option, all will done.